# Un-editable input field

Tags: html

I have got a small code here in which i want to give a particular name and the text filed must be un-editable, how could that be done

```
<form method="get" action="watermark.php">
                <center><h3>YGG Live Player Stats</h3></center>
                <h5>Enter Player name :<h5> <br/><br/><input type="text" name="user" size=50 maxlength=50><br/><br/>
                <input type="Submit" name="Search" value="user">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's `input` field you want made readonly, use the `readonly` attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="user" size=50 maxlength=50 readonly>
```

See the [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) page on the readonly attribute for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do your work with **readonly**

```
<input type="Submit" name="Search" value="user" readonly>
```

Your input field text can only changed by Programming language you use or by javascript. User can't alter it.